# How to get month and year in single column and grouping the data for all the years and months?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

For the below query (sdate is column name and table name is storedata)

```
Collapse
WITH TotalMonths AS (SELECT T1.[Month], T2.[Year]
 FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT Number AS [Month]
FROM MASTER.dbo.spt_values WHERE [Type] = 'p' AND Number BETWEEN 1 AND 12) T1 CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(year, sdate) AS [Year]
FROM storedata) T2))

SELECT CTE.[Year], CTE.[Month], ISNULL(T3.[Sum], 0) areasum
FROM TotalMonths CTE LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT SUM(areasft) [Sum], DATEPART(YEAR, sdate) [Year], DATEPART(MONTH, sdate) [Month]
FROM storedata
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, sdate) ,DATEPART(MONTH, sdate)) T3
ON CTE.[Year] = T3.[Year] AND CTE.[Month] = T3.[Month] WHERE CTE.[Year]>'2007'
ORDER BY CTE.[Year], CTE.[Month]
```

I am getting result set like below.

```
YEAR MONTH AREASUM
2008    1   0
2008    2   1193
2008    3   4230
2008    4   350
2008    5   2200
2008    6   4660
2008    7   0
2008    8   6685
2008    9   0
2008    10  3051
2008    11  7795
2008    12  2940
2009    1   1650
2009    2   3235
2009    3   2850
2009    4   6894
2009    5   3800
2009    6   2250
2009    7   1000
2009    8   1800
2009    9   1550
2009    10  2350
2009    11  0
2009    12  1800
```

But I have to combine both month and year in single column. The reult set should like below.

```
JAN/08   O
FEB/08 1193
.. ..
.. ..
DEC/O9 1800
```

How can I modify my query? (I should display for all the years and months even if there is no area for a month)

Regards,

N.SRIRAM

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, CTE.Month), 7) + '/' + RIGHT(CTE.Year, 2)
```

instead of using your first 2 columns from your `SELECT`.

Comment: Jan/08 0
Jan/08 1193
Jan/08 4230
Jan/08 350
Jan/08 2200
Jan/08 4660
Jan/08 0
Jan/08 6685
Jan/08 0
Jan/08 3051
Jan/08 7795
Jan/08 2940
Jan/09 1650
Jan/09 3235
Jan/09 2850
Jan/09 6894
Jan/09 3800
Jan/09 2250
Jan/09 1000
Jan/09 1800
Jan/09 1550
Jan/09 2350
Jan/09 0
Jan/09 1800
Jan/10 0

Comment: But I am getting same month name for all years. The result set is like below Jan/08 0
Jan/08 1193
Jan/08 4230
Jan/08 350
Jan/08 2200
Jan/08 4660
Jan/08 0
Jan/08 6685
Jan/08 0
Jan/08 3051
Jan/08 7795
Jan/08 2940
Jan/09 1650
Jan/09 3235
Jan/09 2850
Jan/09 6894
Jan/09 3800
Jan/09 2250
Jan/09 1000
Jan/09 1800
Jan/09 1550
Jan/09 2350
Jan/09 0
Jan/09 1800
Jan/10 0

Comment: but I am getting same month name for all years.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that you're getting the right data from your original query, but the wrong format. So

1. Make a view out of the query you originally posted.
2. Build a SELECT query based on that view to give you the format you want.

Let's say you do this:

```
CREATE VIEW wibble AS <your original query goes here>
```

Then you can just query wibble to correct the formatting.

```
select 
case
    when month = 1 then 'Jan/'
    when month = 2 then 'Feb/'
    when month = 3 then 'Mar/'
    when month = 4 then 'Apr/'
    when month = 5 then 'May/'
    when month = 6 then 'Jun/'
    when month = 7 then 'Jul/'
    when month = 8 then 'Aug/'
    when month = 9 then 'Sep/'
    when month = 10 then 'Oct/'
    when month = 11 then 'Nov/'
    when month = 12 then 'Dec/'
    else 'Err'
end || substring(cast(year as CHAR(4)), 3, 2) as yearmonth,
areasum from wibble;
```